# Deploy Shiny App with a scheduled script

Tags: r, deployment, shiny, scheduled-tasks, shiny-server

I have a simple script that in Rstudio works to deploy app:

```
rsconnect::setAccountInfo(name='xx', token='xx', secret='xx/xx')
library(rsconnect)
deployApp("xxx",launch.browser = FALSE)
```

After this prompt appears:

> Update application currently deployed at https://xxx.shinyapps.io/xx/?

that block my scheduled script.

There's a way to skip this request and update the shiny app without manually type "Y" in the Console?

Comment: I feel like there should be a `overwrite` parameter, that is `FALSE` by default. If there isn't one, I think you can ask rstudio about potentially adding it

Comment: Sorry, in truth I tried the script only locally: with crontab the script works without manually typing "Y". The only issue is install the packages required to make the app work also on your server.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to what waskuf said, try adding `forceUpdate = T` to your code.

```
deployApp("xxx", launch.browser = F, forceUpdate = T)
```

Worked for me, at least.

Answer (score 1):

It works if you just write an unquoted Y in your script after the "deployApp" command and run it in one batch. Like this:

```
rsconnect::setAccountInfo(name='xx', token='xx', secret='xx/xx')
library(rsconnect)
deployApp("xxx", launch.browser = FALSE)
Y
```

Just make sure the lines including deployApp(...) and Y are both selected and not seperated by any other commands when executed.